# Ruby on Rails loop executing 2 times

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this rails3 loop:

```
    <div class="row">
      <% recipes.each do |recipe| %>

        <div class="col-md-3"><%= image_tag(recipe.tn_url, class: 'img-rounded') %><br>
        <%= link_to recipe.name, recipe_path(recipe) %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <br><br>
  <% end %>
```

The inner loop:

is executing twice.

I've checked the database and there is only 1 record for each recipe.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say there's only one record for each recipe.  Are there two recipes?

Comment: where did you define `recipes` on which you are calling `each`?